# Можно ли как то добавить анимацию?

Tags: java, android

Я добавил анимацию при переходах между активити... Просто одно активити как бы наезжает на другое...

Но у меня есть активити которое испрользует `FrameLayout` и я в зависимости от того, что нужно я делаю тот или иной `FrameLayout` видимым а другой скрываю...

но смотрится это не так красиво...

Можно ли как то добавить анимацию при смене `FrameLayout`?

У меня есть 2 фрейма

вот в такой разметке

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/registrationFrame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center|top"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExButton
                            style="@style/ExButton"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/stylelogbutton"
                            android:onClick="RegMe"
                            android:text="@string/registration_by_mail"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white" />

                        <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExTextView
                            style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:text="@string/agree"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAutAct3"
                        style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:onClick="goToLogIn"
                        android:text="@string/i_am_already_user"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/loginFrame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvLogAct3"
                        style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/log_in_by_e_mail"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tilEmailLog"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp">

                        <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExEditText
                            android:id="@+id/etEmailLog"
                            style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:hint="@string/email"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tilPasswordLog"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp">

                        <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExEditText
                            android:id="@+id/etPasswordLog"
                            style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:hint="@string/password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExButton
                        android:id="@+id/bLogIn"
                        style="@style/ExButton"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/stylelogbutton"
                        android:onClick="userLogIn"
                        android:text="@string/log_in"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExTextView
                        style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:onClick="forgotPassword"
                        android:text="@string/forgot_your_password"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

у меня есть кнопка при нажатии на которую фраймы меняются. Вот так

```
registrationFrame.animate().alpha(0).start();
        loginFrame.animate().alpha(1).start();
```

Но проблема в том, что когда я устанавливаю `registrationFrame` `alpha(0)`  то он красиво исчезает, но за ним ничего не появляется... Код вообще не реагирует на то, что `loginFrame` установлен `alpha(1)`...

Я сделал по другому, на одну кнопку поставил только функцию

```
registrationFrame.animate().alpha(0).start();
```

А на другую кнопку поставил функцию

```
loginFrame.animate().alpha(1).start();
```

Жму на первую все исчезает, жму на вторую ничего не появляется.((

Потом я попробовал одну и ту же функцию поставить на один и тоже фрайм `loginFrame` на эти 2 кнопки, только на в первом случае функция устанавливает `alpha(0)` а во втором `alpha(1)`...

Все работает для этого фрайма, он красиво исчезает, потом появляется.

Но почему это работает, только для одного и того же фрайма? Почему не получается сделать, чтоб один исчезал, а другой появлялся?

Comment: А как у вас изначально скрыт фрейм который не виден? если через `setVisibility(View.GONE)`, то его сначала сделать видимым, а уже потом анимировать альфу, не забыв перед анимированным переходом к альфе 1f установить сначала альфу в 0f

Comment: @xkor а есть разница если я буду с `f` ставить или без нее... Оно ж автоматически конвертирует...?

Comment: Да в принципе тут нет, я просто люблю когда по константе которую в параметр пихаешь виден тип параметра.

Comment: @xkor и еще такой вопрос... Есть ли разница в анимации, если анимировать через файл (создать обьект анимации, указать файл и стартануть этот обьект через метод `startAnimation(animation)` ) или сделать так как вы говорите? Я имею ввиду что в вашем случае мы присваеваем альфу непосредственно вью элементу, а в случае использования того, анимации с указанием параметров через файл, будут ли в итоге конечные значения присвоены вью элементу? Вот это сказал)) Не уверен, что вы поняли мою мысль...

Comment: На сколько помню если через [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) (res/animator/ папка), то будут, там анимируются непосредственно свойства вьюх. Если через [View Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) (res/anim/ папка), то нет, это устаревший фреймворк анимаций и там всё довольно кисло.

Comment: @xkor просто я делаю анимацию выключения первого вью с помощью файла и показываю второй вью с помощью вашего метода. То есть один выключаю файлом, второй включаю вашим методом. Но потом, когда я хочу сделать тоже самое но наоборот, второе вью выключаю с помощью файла, а первое вью включаю вашим методом, то первое вью не хочет показываться... хотя второе выключается... и остается пустой экран.

Comment: @xkor а вы случайно не в курсе есть ли у вашего метода слушатель? и можно ли установить время задержки показа `duration`?

Comment: ну посмотрите все методы доступные после animate(). через автокомплит и увидите всё что вам нужно)

Comment: @xkor нашел, точно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, например вот так:

```
frame1.animate().alpha(1f).start(); // то что показываем, изначально должно быть с альфой 0
frame2.animate().alpha(0f).start(); // то что скрываем
```

Это через прозрачность, если хотите перемещение то так:

```
frame1.animate().x(0f).start(); // то что показываем, изначально должно быть скрыто за экраном
frame2.animate().x(-frame2.getX()).start(); // то что скрываем
```

А вообще вам наверное вместо FrameLayout надо фрагменты использовать для переключения между различными вариантами UI. Там и простые анимации переходов между ними включить можно буквально парой строк кода (не помню правда какими).

Comment: Вроде как работает, только не до конца, не могу разобраться почему... Я дополнил вопрос, можете пожалуйста посмотреть, что я делаю не так?